# How to use a component multiple times while passing different data to it?

Tags: vue.js, notifications, components, vue-component, snackbar

I'm trying to create a snackbar component for showing simple notifications. It can be used at many places in the entire application as well as on a single page as well. I've created a component as child component and imported it in the parent component where i want to use it. In this parent component many times this child can be used. How should i implement in a way that each time this component is called it gets its appropriate data(Ex. for error color=red text="error",   for success color="green" message="success).

Any suggestions on how to implement it?

```
parent.vue----------------------------

<snackbar
      :snackbar="snackbar"
      :color="color"
      :text="message"
      v-on:requestClose="close"
    />


data() {
    return {
      snackbar: false,
      color: "orange",
      timeout: 3000,
      message: "calling from employee compoenent"
    };
  },
  methods: {
    hello() {
      console.log("button clicked!!!");
      this.snackbar = true;
    },
    close() {
      this.snackbar = false;
    },


child.vue-----------------------------------------------

<template>
  <v-snackbar v-model="snackbar" right top :timeout="timeout" :color="color"
    >{{ text }}
    <v-btn dark text @click.native="$emit('requestClose')">Close</v-btn>
  </v-snackbar>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "snackbar",
  data() {
    return {
      timeout: 3000
    };
  },
  props: ["snackbar", "text", "color"],

};
</script>

<style></style>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### *Recommended* would be to create a custom wrapper *`Vue plugin`*

plugins/snackbar/index.js

```
import snackbar from './snackbar.vue'

export default {
  install (Vue) {
    // INSTALL
    if (this.installed) return
    this.installed = true

    // RENDER
    const root = new Vue({ render: h => h(snackbar) })
    root.$mount(document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div')))

    // APIs
    let apis = Vue.prototype['$snackbar'] = {
      show: ({ text="Foo", color="blue" }) => root.$emit('show', { text, color }), // SHOW
      hide: () => root.$emit('hide') // HIDE
    }

    Vue.prototype['$snackbar'] = apis
    Vue.snackbar = apis
  }
}
```

plugins/snackbar/snackbar.vue

```
<template>
  <v-snackbar right top v-model="show" :timeout="timeout" :color="color">
    {{ text }}
    <v-btn dark text @click.native="this.show = false">Close</v-btn>
  </v-snackbar>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "snackbar",

  data() {
    return {
      show,
      timeout: 3000,
      text: "",
      color: ""
    };
  },

  mounted () {
   // LISTENING :: SHOW
   this.$root.$on('show', ({ text, color }) => {      
    this.text = text
    this.color = color
    this.show = true
   })

   // LISTENING :: HIDE
   this.$root.$on('hide', () => this.show = false)
  }
};
</script>
```

// main.js

```
import Snackbar from './plugins/snackbar/index.js'
Vue.use(Snackbar)
```

> To *`show` / `hide`* it in *any* component

```
this.$snackbar.show({ text: "Foo bar", color: "red" }) // OR
Vue.snackbar.show({ text: "Foo bar", color: "red" })
```

*As per use case, you can keep updating your plugin with more params / APIs.*

---

### *Alternative:* By using an *`event bus`*

event-bus/bus.js

```
// Create an event bus
import Vue from 'vue'
export default new Vue()
```

app.vue

```
<template>
 // Render the component in app.vue
 <v-snackbar 
  right top 
  v-model="snackbar.show" 
  :timeout="snackbar.timeout" 
  :color="snackbar.color"
 >
  {{ snackbar.text }}
  <v-btn 
   dark text 
   @click.native="this.snackbar.show = false"
  >
   Close
  </v-btn>
 </v-snackbar>
</template>

<script>
import bus from './event-bus/bus.js'

export default {
 data () {
  return {
   snackbar: {
    show: false,
    text: '',
    color: '',
    timeout: 3000
   }
  }
 },

 mounted () {
  // LISTEN TO SHOW
  bus.$on('show', ({ text, color }) => {
   this.snackbar.text = 'foo'
   this.snackbar.color = 'red'
   this.snackbar.show = true
  })

  // LISTEN TO HIDE
  bus.$on('hide', () => this.snackbar.show = false)
 }
}
</script>
```

> To *`show` / `hide`* snackbar from *any* component

```
import bus from './event-bus/bus.js

export default {
 mounted () {
  bus.emit('show', { text: 'Foo bar baz', color: 'orange' }) // TO SHOW
  // bus.emit('hide') // TO HIDE
 }
}
```

---

### *Another way*: By using *`Vuex`*

*Render the `<v-snackbar>` in app.vue as done in an alternative approach & use `Vuex` `state` / `getters` to pass the value to the `props` of v-snackbar.*

Answer (score 3):

I did it by using combination of global components and Vuex. The answer is a bit lengthy because I provide example along the description, please bear with me :)

I first create a snackbar store with `color` and `text` as its `state` and a `setSnackbar()` `action` which receives color and text as params. Then you can create your `Snackbar` component and don't forget to have your getters, actions mapped into it. Some code snippet:

```
// snackbar component
<template>
  <v-snackbar v-model="snackbar.show" :color="snackbar.color" :timeout="6000" bottom right>
    {{ snackbar.text }}
    <v-btn dark text @click="snackbarClosed()">Close</v-btn>
  </v-snackbar>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from "vue";
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from "vuex";

export default Vue.extend({
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(["snackbar"])
  },
  methods: {
    snackbarClosed() {
      this.resetSnackbar();
    },
    ...mapActions(["resetSnackbar"])
  }
});
</script>
```

```
// snackbar store
const state = {
  snackbar: {
    show: false,
    text: '',
    color: ''
  }
};
const getters = {
  snackbar: (state: any) => state.snackbar
};
const actions = {
  async setSnackbar({ commit }, params) {
    commit('updateSnackbar', Object.assign({}, { show: true }, params))
  },
  async resetSnackbar({ commit }) {
    const setting: SnackbarSetting = {
      show: false,
      text: '',
      color: ''
    };
    commit('updateSnackbar', setting)
};
const mutations = {
  updateSnackbar: (state: any, snackbar: SnackbarSetting) => {
    state.show = snackbar.show;
    state.text = snackbar.text;
    state.color = snackbar.color;
  }
};
```

To make `Snackbar` component globally available, import your `Snackbar` component into your `main.ts` and add the line `Vue.component('Snackbar', Snackbar);` before `new Vue`. Its purpose is to register your `Snackbar` component globally before initializing the Vue instance. Example:

```
// main.ts
import Snackbar from './components/Snackbar.vue';

Vue.component('Snackbar', Snackbar);

new Vue({
...
```

Before you want to display your snackbar in the app, by my recommendation you should place `<Snackbar />` in your `App.vue` so that the snackbar can appear before your components and you won't be facing missing snackbar when changing between components.

When you want to display your snackbar, just do this in your component:

```
// any of your component
methods: {
  someEvent() {
    this.someApiCall({
      // some data passing
    }).then(() => {
      this.setSnackbar({
        text: 'Data has been updated.',
        color: 'success'
      });
    }).catch(() => {
      this.setSnackbar({
        text: 'Failed to update data.',
        color: 'error'
      });
    });
  },
  ...mapActions(['setSnackbar'])
}
```

Hope you can work it out, please do not hesitate to let me know if you need something. Here's some extra material for you: [Global component registration](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html#Automatic-Global-Registration-of-Base-Components)

Answer (score -1):

you can watch for props in child this'll make color changes when any change happen in parent:

```
watch: {
color: function(value) {
"add color value to your dom css class"
}
}
```